# Nested Filter in Scala Either on top of Future[Try[Int]]

Tags: scala, async-await, future, either

I am beginner is scala , I am trying to implement a filter logic on top of a `Either`. Now I have a function `getTaskId` that returns `Future[Try[Int]]` and my `filter logic` is based on that `Int`. Now since `filter` expects `boolean` , I am unable to return the same in below code snippet .

```scala
val records: List[CommittableRecord[Either[Throwable, MyEvent]]] = ???
records.filter { 
  (x: CommittableRecord[Either[Throwable,MyEvent]]) => 
    x.value match {
      case Right(event: MyEvent) =>
        getTaskId(event.get("task").get) filter {
            case Success(value)     => value > 1
            case Failure(exception) => false
          }
      case Left(_) => false
    }
}
```

I am getting the error for `filter` on function `getTaskId` that returns `Future[Try[Int]]`

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Try[Int]]
 required: Boolean
```

So basically `filter` on top of `Future` returning another `Future` but the parent `filter` is expecting a `boolean`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question is not clear enough to answer the question. Are you filtering the ```List[Either]```?

Comment: Your function should probably return a `Future[Either[A, B]]` instead of `Either[A, B]`, because your function is asynchronous.

Comment: @TausifSayyad yes I am `filtering`  `List[Either]`

Comment: @curiousguy what are you want to get in the end of your filtering? Which type?

Comment: @BorisAzanov this should be my filter result   `CommittableRecord[Either[Throwable,MyEvent]]`

Comment: https://impurepics.com/posts/2020-10-03-always-traverse.html

Answer (score 2):

You faced two difficult features in scala here:

1. A lot of syntactic sugar
2. Best practice in scala is not awaiting `Future`s result inside you some business logic using: `Await.result(future, timeout)`. You should use it only *at the end of the universe* (in most cases: at the end of your program).

So, I would advice to refactor your current logic from having filtered `List[CommittableRecord]` in result to make result is non-blocking - `Future[List[CommittableRecord]]` with filtered list of records. You can work with this future, like it's just another data-container (like `Option[T]`) and at the end of your program call blocking operation like `Await.result`.

Example of code:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future.sequence
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

case class Task()

type MyEvent = Map[String, Task]
case class CommittableRecord(value: Either[Throwable, MyEvent])

def getTaskId(task: Task): Future[Try[Int]] = ???

val records: List[CommittableRecord] = List.empty[CommittableRecord]
val result: Future[List[CommittableRecord]] = sequence(
  records.map(
    x =>
      (x.value match {
        case Left(_) => Future(false)
        case Right(value) =>
          getTaskId(value.get("task").get)
            .map {
              case Failure(_) => false
              case Success(id) => id > 1
            }
      }).map(_ -> x)
  )
).map(
  idMoreThen1AndRecordList =>
    idMoreThen1AndRecordList.collect {
      case (true, record) => record
    }
)
```

or, after some refactoring and replacing lambda-expressions to functions:

```scala
def isTaskIdMoreThenOneAndRecord(record: CommittableRecord): Future[(Boolean, CommittableRecord)] =
  (record.value match {
    case Left(_) => Future(false)
    case Right(value) =>
      getTaskId(value.get("task").get)
        .map(tryId => tryId.fold(_ => false, _ > 1))
  }).map(_ -> record)

def filterRecordsWithTaskIdMoreThenOne(
    isMoreOneAndRecordList: List[(Boolean, CommittableRecord)]
): List[CommittableRecord] =
  isMoreOneAndRecordList.collect {
    case (true, record) => record
  }

val result: Future[List[CommittableRecord]] =
  sequence(records.map(isTaskIdMoreThenOneAndRecord))
    .map(filterRecordsWithTaskIdMoreThenOne)
```

So, in result you will have `Future[List[CommittableRecord]]` and you can work with filtered records using `map` function:

```scala
result.map((filteredRecords: List[CommittableRecord]) => \*do something with filtered records*\)
```

or you can compose two non-blocking operations (for example your list and another non-blocking function) using `flatMap`.

Useful links:

- read more about Future on [scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)
- [article about lambda expressions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expression-in-scala/)
- [some best practices](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/4-concurrency-parallelism.md) in scala concurrent